# CSS div elements overlaying when they shouldn't be

Tags: html, css

I was wondering why the children comments I have are getting put into the header of the next parent comment which they aren't even related to. I tried looking at errors in my html that may cause this but as far as I can tell there aren't any.

The website that contains the issue I am talking about is:

http://web.engr.illinois.edu/~hauger3/

Thank you to anybody who knows why this is happening and can tell me how to fix it.

Note: It will probably be better to look at the html through developer tools as the source looks nasty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your using `pull-right` which floats the element.

You can easily fix this by adding `clear: both;` to `.panel`

Comment: Thanks that worked. Could you explain what "clear: both" does to fix this?

Comment: There's a decent article about this at css-tricks.com, the section called 'The Great Collapse' is literally the same problem you just had http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Answer (score 0):

It's because of `.pull-right` class in child comment that adds floating `float: right`. Change it to padding for example.